# How to form a gerund from “practise”?

Tags: orthography, british-english, gerunds

I (think) I know the difference between *practise* (verb) and *practice* (non-verb).

However, I am not sure which form I should use in cases like the following ones:

> I love **practising** the guitar.
>   You can try **practising** with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is tagged "British English". This answer addresses British English.

*Practice* is a noun. *Practise* is a verb. A participle is a verbal form so would use *s*, whether that is *practised* or *practising*.

Even when the word is a gerund (which functions as a noun), it's identical in form to the present participle so it uses an *s*.

> My practising the piano upset the neighbours.
>
> The neighbours dug a tunnel to escape from my piano practice.

Comment: So, practising is always with an 's'.
Thank you Andrew!

Comment: Hmm. The pond-divide strikes again? My browser thinks "practising" is misspelled, and wants to correct it to "practicing"; which matches my experience.

Comment: @LyK: only if you're in England, apparently.

Comment: Most Americans are unaware of any distinction, thank gods, and simply think of _practise_ as a British variant spelling, like _tyre_.

Comment: At least the BrE rule is nice and simple. It's always open to others to add a complementary answer for American English, preferably marking it explicitly as such because the question is specifically tagged "British English".

Comment: @Martha Yeah, I notice the same with my spellchecker too. But mine doesn't even seem to recognize "practise"
@ Andrew Yes, mostly I was interested in the BrE "version". However, anyone is free to submit an answer for american English too!

Comment: @Martha re: browser - I find that strange, because it's *practiSing* on both sides of the pond isn't it. It's only the noun that we spell with a "c" (also in *licence* and a few other words). Which browser?  2. No not *only in England*, also in the rest of the UK (and other countries using British English).

Comment: @TrevorD: Check the AHD.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, what's the AHD?

Comment: @TrevorD: The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language. Here's a link and entry showing that the verb _practice_ is used in the US:  **prac·tise**  (prkts)
v. & n. Chiefly British
Variant of practice.

 http://www.thefreedictionary.com/practise You can confirm this by looking up _practice_.

Comment: That's very, very wrong. BrE does not spell the verb with a c.